# Access git on raspberry from IDE

Tags: git, url, phpstorm, raspberry-pi2

I put a Git server on my raspberry pi. Everything works fine by command line.

I would like to use this git on PHPStorm but they ask for a remote depository url.

But how to access my remote depository? What's the url?

I can access my raspberry through the internet...

<_URL_OF_THE_RASPBERRY_>:/gitData/project.git doesn't work :(

Please help me I really need it,

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing a remote git repo on an RPi is no different than a git repo on any other platform.  You want to look for a tutorial on `git+ssh`, several of which are around in a variety of places.  The general form of the command would be:

```
git clone <user>@<ip-address>:/path-to-repo
```

of course, this presumes that you've been successful in setting up SSH so that you can log in using a command of the following form:

```
ssh <user>@<ip-address>
```

If you still need to make that work, have a look at the documentation for the `ssh-copy-id` command.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but all you tell me is working fine but when I try to do it on PHPStorm it says that it is not working :/

Comment: Try cloning the repo then importing the project into PHPStorm.  It should then use the configurations that were set by the command line.  Also, look at your git configs in PHPStorm, and use the system git instead of the bundled git.